# beneficial in terms of performance

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

is it better to declare Webservice class object instances as static as the .asmx webservice classes have only static methods.

what i want is that i declare and instantiate webservice asmx class as static in aspx Page Behind Class.

and on every event call on that page i could perform operation against webservice methods.

is it beneficial in terms of performance?

Thanks

Usama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the static methods in the WebService, because it is a Disposable type, so then you use static class, it will cause some merory problems.

You should use only instances of the WebService class, and in the **using** expression